# Law of large numbers for transformed and non-transformed random variables

Tags: expected-value, law-of-large-numbers

Law of large numbers states that:

If $X_1, \dots X_n \sim p(x)$ are IID, then $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \rightarrow \mathbb{E}_{p(x)}\{X\}= \mu$, where $X \sim p(x)$.

Below is what I'm having trouble connecting to this, as this is new notation for me from an online lecture:

If we have a function $f(X)$ of some random variable $X$ and a pdf $p(x)$, then by LLN $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(X_i) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}_{p(x)}\{f(X)\}$, where $X_1, \dots , X_n \sim p(x)$

Is $p(x)$ referring to the transformed PDF of $X$ under $f(\cdot)$ or a different distribution? Or is this notation too ambiguous to tell?

So in the first case, $X_1, \dots X_n \sim g(x)$, therefore $f(X_1), \dots, f(X_n)$ are random variables with pdf $p(x)$, where $p(x)$ can be computed using the formula for transformation of a random variable. Hence, we can use LLN to state that the summation will eventually converge to $\mathbb{E}\{f(X)\}$ where $X \sim p(x)$, which can also be written as $\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}\{f(X)\}$.

Comment: $p(x)$ is simply the density of $X$. This remains true both in the original LLN statement at the start of your question and in the generalized version with $f(X_i)$ replacing $X_i$. There is no need in the theorem to transform the pdf.

Comment: The notation is awful but it's relatively clear.  (One has to make assumptions about how "$X_i,$" "$X,$" and "$x$" might be related and the specific meaning of $p$ is not entirely evident). However, in the statement you are asking about, the *only* random variable in sight is $X,$ whence "$\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}$" *must* refer to expectation relative to $X.$

Comment: @whuber I see, so the expectation being considered in the case with $f(\cdot)$ is not the expectation of $f(X)$ w.r.t its own pdf but rather the expectation of $f(X)$ *under* $p(x)$. If I had omitted the $p(x)$ subscript and just had $\mathbb{E}\{f(X)\}$, would this imply that I would have an expectation under the transformed PDF of $X$ that I talk about in the question?

Comment: As @GordonSmyth pointed out, this makes little sense.  *$X$ is the random variable.*  All expectations are taken with respect to its distribution.  In fact, even when $X$ has a PDF, $f(X)$ might not have one.  As an example, let $f(X)$ be the sign of $X:$ now $f(X)$ is a binary variable.

Comment: @whuber So in that case, is it true that $E_{p(x)} \{f(X)\}$ is the true mean $\mu$ of $f(X)$ iff $f(X)$ has a PDF and $p(x)$ is that PDF?

Comment: It's even simpler: when the probability law of $X$ is $p,$  $E_p[f(X)]$ is the expectation, or "true mean," of $f(X).$  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467961 for one explanation or search our site for [LOTUS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=lotus) for more.

Comment: @whuber This clears everything up, thank you!