In the Law of the Unconscious Statistician, is $p(Y=y_1) = p(X\in g^{-1}(y_1))$ a convention or can it be derived?
There's something I am not really sure about the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.
Let $X$ be a random variable and $Y=g(X)$ be another one.
When we fix $y$, say, $y=4$, we have that $p(Y=4)=p(X=4)+p(X=5)$.
Why do we have that? Is it a convention - i.e. we fix $p(Y=y_1) = p(X\in g^{-1}(y_1))$? Or is it possible to derive it from the assumption?
I doubt the second hypothesis put forward would be likely, since we merely only start from the assumption that $Y=g(X)$.


There are no assumptions or conventions here: this is a basic consequence of the mathematical definitions of functions and events.  It comes down to the meaning of "$\Pr(Y=4):$" that is a shorthand for the probability of the event ${\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega)=4}.$  Perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467961/ answers your questions?

Yes, indeed $(g\circ X) ^{-1}=X^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$. I now understand

... Exactly right!
